# Appending each a value from an array to it's equivalent html-node

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have an array of objects:

```
comment: "https://www.facebook.com/groups/2388163605/permalink/10151045693478606/"
comments: Array[1]
created: "48 minuter sen"
img: "http://graph.facebook.com/589136752/picture"
link: "http://www.facebook.com/589136752"
message: "gbg - sthlm 31/7. finnes: 3 platser. 0703 05 45 65"
name: "Jack Johansson"
sortvar: 1342676288
```

Using this Array and mustache. I generate a list of html list-elements. However I don't use the "Name" variable. It's in there for a debug function. When the debug is run I want to add/append the name-variable to the beginning of it's equivalent list-node. What is a good way of doing this? I would prefer to not create a new template in mustache.

I believe the solution is something like:

```
foreach(item in array){
  $(li).append('<p>'+item.name+'</p>');
}
```

But this will add the item.name all list items. I want to add the first item.name to the first list item, and the second item.name to the second etc.

Comment: What is the html(html-node) that you want append to?

Comment: Let's say it's list-items. It's rather the matching/selecting correct node that i'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand Mustache,

If you want to add Name attribute to an Js Object only while debugging some logic like,

```
var x={
comment: "https://www.facebook.com/groups/2388163605/permalink/10151045693478606/",
comments: Array[1],
created: "48 minuter sen",
img: "http://graph.facebook.com/589136752/picture",
link: "http://www.facebook.com/589136752",
message: "gbg - sthlm 31/7. finnes: 3 platser. 0703 05 45 65",
sortvar: 1342676288
};

if(debug)x.name="Jack Johansson";
```

can be used, again I am totally unaware of mustache.

Do you want something like:

```
var index = 0;
foreach(item in array){
  $("#mainslector li").eq(index++).append('<p>'+item.name+'</p>');
}
```

Just saw your update, still not exactly sure of what you want, this just demonstrates selecting nth li for nth element.

Comment: Nevermind mustache, I updated the question with what I want to do.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @KristofferNolgren I just updated the answer, sorry that I dont understand you well.